# Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application "

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I have 64 bit eclipse and configured this with 64bit jvm  when i try to connect `MS Access (32 bit MS office)` it gives me error

```
Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between 
the Driver and Application
```

I also defined DSN in `c:\windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` in my Win 7 64 bit machine and Even tried by both 32 bit and 64 bit jvm but everytime i got the same error but when i run the same code with 32 bit Eclipse its working fine, but i have to run with 64 bit Eclipse, Please help

Answer (score 2):

Try using [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) instead of the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver.

UCanAccess is pure Java, so there shouldn't be any 32-bit/64-bit issues talking to an Access database with it.  Besides, the JDBC-ODBC bridge driver is no longer included in Java 8, so you'll have to migrate away from it if you want your application to run on Java 8.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc) contains instructions on how to set up Eclipse to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use a 32 bit ODBC driver from a 32 bit application. You either need 64 bit Access ODBC driver (which is not possible if you have 32 bit office iirc), or you need to switch to 32 bit Java/Eclipse.

Otherwise, look at [the answer by Luke Woodward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27115707/466862) to use UCanAccess.

Comment: Working fine now, i used 32bit JRE with 32 bit ODBC, its working fine, Thanks mark for giving me aleternative